# Cannot debug some drivers with IDA

Tags: ida, debugging, kernel-mode, driver

For some drivers I can use the following **WinDBG** command:

```
bu driver!DriverEntry
```

However there are some drivers that cannot be debugged this way. IDA output window displays the following error message:

```
WaitForEvent() failed; please make sure that all unresolved bpts/expressions could be evaluated before continuing
```

or breakpoint is completely ignored. This command does not help either:

```
sxe ld:driver
```

I tried to replace the first byte of driver's **DriverEntry** code with **CC** opcode (**int 3**). After that virtual machine window silently closes.

Does anybody know how to break on **DriverEntry** of such driver? Thanks.

Comment: Can someone please explain what the error message mean?